# Placement of the "comma" in this context

Tags: grammar, commas

In the commentary section of a book titled *MACBETH* I found a sentence:

> Macbeth fights, Siward killing him.

Shouldn't the *comma* be placed after **Siward?**

My experience tells me that it is a misprint but the following factors are making me post the question:

1. *The weirdness of the English language.*
2. *I found it in a reputable book*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the comma should be placed after Siward.

As it reads now, with the comma after *fights*, it means that Siward killed Macbeth. It's actually grammatical, though the phrasing is kind of awkward.